# Is it a horrible idea to leave a new job and take a better one?

Tags: new-job, quitting

Is it a horrible idea to leave a new job and take a better one?

I am currently a student who is about 12-18 months away from finishing my degree in Accounting. I then plan to pursue my MBA & CPA while working FT/PT in my field. I don’t have any direct accounting experience yet (which is important in the field) but I also don’t have the time to commit to a 40hr/week internship or job.

3 months ago, I took a part time job (15 hrs/week) at an amazing marketing firm as a receptionist. 
There is another person who I ‘job share’ with who is the office manager/ bookkeeper/ receptionist who originally handled the both positions.

My duties only include answering phones, prepping for meetings, etc. when the coworker has time off- I don’t manage the office or get to do any bookkeeping.

The office is not busy at all, so most of the time I work on homework (as suggested by my supervisor) and not actually do anything for the firm. Leaving would minimally jeopardize workflow/ productivity.

As PT, I don’t get benefits

My plan was to work at the marketing firm until I graduate- and they are aware of that. I LOVE the culture and the pay is good- I have absolutely no complaints about the company.

But- I am worried I won’t have enough experience in my industry when I start the real job search in a year or so. You also need to have 1 yr of experience in accounting to get a CPA.

I applied and was offered a position at another company as an “Accounting  Executive Assistant”

It is a great combination of my experience as an admin assistant/receptionist and my future in accounting. I would handle a lot of entry-level accounting that would give me a little boost when I look for FT accounting jobs after graduation.

I would supervise 2 people (something I’ve yet to have the opportunity to do)

I love the culture and know several people at the company- it is also a great fit.

It is twice as many hours and better pay, with full benefits AND is flexible with school.

Would it be ok to leave my job at the marketing firm after 3 months to take the accounting job?

If so, how should I approach t

Comment: Hey mnl, and welcome to [workplace.se]! Questions asking 'what should I do?' or 'which job should I take?' are off-topic as explained in the [help/on-topic], so your question is likely to be put [on hold](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) in its current form. Could you please [edit] the question to focus it on a practical, answerable question based on a problem you face? Having a choice of jobs is a boon, not a problem!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the question is about having a short time at a job on a resume and how that will affect future jobs.  There are times when it is ok to leave a job after a short time:

- When you're a student
- When you have another job to go to, and which you expect to stay at for a longer time
- When the job is not safe or tolerable for some reason and you'll be able to either leave it off your resume or explain why you left ("Paychecks were bouncing so I found a more stable job.")
- When you have other longer term jobs on your resume and this is the only short term job
- When you're a contractor or move around a lot and are going for jobs where that is an asset

There are probably other reasons too, but if you have another job lined up, and you're a student, you should be able to get away with it.  For a 3 month job and as a student, you can easily leave it off your resume (since it also hasn't given you any noteable experience to help with another job).

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not a horrible idea.  I think that the only thing you really need to consider is how you will handle the increased workload (you'll be working more hours) and decreased time to study (this is a combination of working more hours and not being able to do your homework at work as you do now).  If you are confident that this is a great opportunity for you, you should take it.

Tell your current employer that while you love your current job and you're very grateful for the opportunity to work for them, you have been presented with an opportunity that you cannot turn down.  Your reasons for taking this new position are amazingly compelling: it gets you relevant experience for your career, the pay is commensurately higher, and you will receive benefits at this new position.

If you have a friend or fellow student who you think would be a good fit for this position and is looking for a job, you can offer to share your friend's details with your current employer.  You'll help out a friend and you'll help your current employer fill their need for a part-time receptionist.  This is not a requirement for leaving your current role, it's simply potentially a nice thing that you can do.

The remaining question is how you handle this position in the future.  In general, unless there is something about this position that is relevant to a position that you are applying for, you do not need to include it on your resume.  I think that the only reason that you would need to list it on a resume would be if you were using someone from your current position as a reference for a future role, but it seems unlikely since your current position isn't relevant to your future career.